# C# - Unable to use Linq Batch in For Each Loop Correctly

Tags: c#, linq

New to C#. I have a .csv file of 200 rows which I read lat/lngs columns from into a json format, which I want to post to an API, but there is a limit to the amount of items that can be posted to the API (50) at once. I read about the linq batch function, which I have used in the first code snippet below, but when I debug the foreach statement the helperPostBatch.Addresses is set to 200 items straight away instead of 50. I'm sure I am making a very basic mistake.

```
var helperPost = new JsonHelperPost();
var helperPostBatch = new JsonHelperPost();
List<JsonHelperPost.Response> recordsPost = new List<JsonHelperPost.Response>();

helperPost.Addresses = JsonHelperPost.ReadCoordinateCSV(wbPath).ToList();

int batchCount = 50;

foreach (var batch in helperPost.Locations.Batch(batchCount))
{
    helperPostBatch.Addresses= helperPost.Addresses;
    recordsPost = API.ApiIHSPostRequest(helperPostBatch);
}
```

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> ReadCoordinateCSV(string path)
{
    int index = getColumnIndex("Lat");

    using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
    {
        parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };

        parser.ReadFields(); // read past the header
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            yield return parser.ReadFields().Skip(index).Take(2).ToArray();
        }
    }
}

public List<string[]> Addresses{ get; set; }

public class Address
{
    public string Lat { get; set; }
    public string Long { get; set; }
}

public class Details
{
    public float Test1 { get; set; }
    public float Test2 { get; set; }
    public float Test3 { get; set; }
    public float Test4 { get; set; }
    public float Test5 { get; set; }
    public float Test6 { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Address address;
    public Details details;
}
```

```
public class API
{
    public static List<JsonHelperPost.Response> ApiIHSPostRequest(JsonHelperPost helperPost)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(helperPost);
            string apiResultPost;
            var endpoint = new Uri("https://api.connect");
            var payload = new StringContent(result, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Username:password");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            apiResultPost = client.PostAsync(endpoint, payload).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            var recordsPost = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonHelperPost.Response>>(apiResultPost);
            return recordsPost;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside your loop you are using `helperPostBatch.Addresses= helperPost.Addresses` instead of `batch`

Comment: Thank you. So helperPost.Addresses would be batch.Addresses. Silly mistake apologies.

Comment: C# is a language of types. The type of `batch` is going to be `IEnumerable<typeof(Locations)[]>` so it wouldn't have an `.Addresses` member. (What is the type of `Locations` and how does it relate to `Addresses`?). Also, shouldn't that be `Chunk` and not `Batch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var batch in helperPost.Addresses.Batch(batchCount))
{
    // Create a new instance of JsonHelperPost for this batch
    var helperPostBatch = new JsonHelperPost
    {
        Addresses = batch.ToList() // Assign only the current batch
    };

    // Add the responses from this batch to the recordsPost list
    recordsPost.AddRange(API.ApiIHSPostRequest(helperPostBatch));
}
```